# Cómo mover el signo negativo en este SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo un Select que  muestra cuentas y balances pero los mismos deben de mostrarse con "0" delante para hacer un total de 14 posiciones, el inconveniente es que cuando los pongo con replicate toma en cuenta el signo de menos, y deseo que cuando sea negativo  el signo esté delante de los "0" agregados y este se tome en cuenta en el total de las 14 posiciones.

ejemplo:`-0000012331411`

```
select 
replace( a.CUENTA, '-','') as cuenta, 
a.CUENTAG,fecha_efectiva=@fecha into #tmp 
from ContConsWeb.[dbo].[analitico] a

select 
a.CUENTAG, 
REPLICATE('0',14-LEN(LTRIM(CAST(b.[bal_mes_ano_act] AS bigint))))+LTRIM(CAST (b.[bal_mes_ano_act] AS bigint)) AS Balance_Actual
from #tmp a 
inner join #Saldos b on a.cuenta=b.cuenta 
where b.[bal_mes_ano_act]<>0 
GROUP BY a.CUENTAG, b.cuenta,b.bal_mes_ano_act 
order by a.CUENTAG
```

El resultado es:

[image: Resultado del query]

Comment: ¿`b.bal_mes_ano_act` siempre es negativo o puede ser positivo?

Comment: puede ser tanto positivo como negativo

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución.

Primero obtener el signo que quieres por delante, mediante un case. Luego hacer un replicate 14 (ceros). Luego extraer el balance de la cuenta como bigint, y aplicar la función ABS para convertirlo a varchar(14)
y concatenar ambos, para hacer un right 14, de manera que si tienes 
00000000000000+734265 y obtienes los 14 dígitos de la derecha, tienes 00000000734265

```
drop table if exists #saldos;

Create table #saldos
             (
             cuenta          varchar(14)
           , bal_mes_ano_act varchar(10)
             );

insert into #saldos(cuenta
                  , bal_mes_ano_act)
values
       ( '1234', '734265' ),
       ( '1235', '-734265' );

drop table if exists #tmp;

create table #tmp
             (
             cuenta varchar(14)
             );

insert into #tmp(cuenta)
values
       ( '1234' ),
       ( '1235' );


   select *
     , CONCAT(case
                   when CAST(b.bal_mes_ano_act AS bigint) < 0 then '-'
              END, RIGHT(concat(REPLICATE('0', 14), CAST(ABS(CAST(b.bal_mes_ano_act AS bigint)) AS VARCHAR(14))), CASE WHEN CAST(b.bal_mes_ano_act AS bigint) < 0 then 13 ELSE 14 END )) AS Balance
       from #tmp AS a
                 inner join #Saldos AS b on a.cuenta = b.cuenta;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchisimas gracias por responder javi, efectivamente mueve el signo corectamente, pero el balance se convierte a 15 posiciones al agregarle el signo delante, busco que se mantenga en las 14 eliminando uno de los "0" agregados

Comment: Ya te he modificado la respuesta. Puedes hacer un case para extraer 14 o 13 en función del signo del balance.

Comment: gracias nuevamente por tomarte el tiempo a responder, me funcionó perfecto.